# n nested for loops in a method with n as input

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, recursion

I have a function, and one of the inputs is the number of for loops that I need to do. In other words, the function is:

```
 double MethodName(otherinputs, int numberofForLoops)
```

The number of for loops, however, is the number of nested forloops. In other words, if `numberofForLoops = 3`, then I would run

```
 for(int i blah blah blah)
 {
      for(int j blah blah blah)
      {
            for(int k blah blah blah)
            { actual function }
      }
 }
```

How would I structure the method?

Comment: does your `actual function` depend on `i, j, k` and other parameters?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: No there is no dependency, and c#

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that directly. What you can do is use recursion, and make a single recursive call for each loop that you need (and have one loop in the method)

Comment: Can you give a few more details

Comment: its unclear what you're trying to accomplish without more context. Do you know about recursion?

Comment: I've had some experience with it, but it's been direct. It's really unclear to me what I'm doing in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

So if your `actual function` does not depend on `i, j, k`, you can substitute your `n` loops with just one.

```
for(int j blah^n){
   actual function
}
```

The number of times it will be executed is the same as the number of times `n` nested loops will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is very much like incrementing a Very Long Number (in a varied base BTW).

Since you have an undetermined amount of loops, you need to pass their count along with their limits:

```
    ret_type do_loops(int numberOfForLoops, int limits[])
```

The `do_loops` function shall keep the current state in the similar array:

```
    ret_type do_loops(int numberOfForLoops, int limits[]) {
        int indices[numberOfForLoops] = { 0 };
```

and always try to increment the lowest possible dimension:

```
    ret_type do_loops(int numberOfForLoops, int limits[]) {
        int indices[numberOfForLoops] = { 0 };
        int index = 0;
        while (1) {
            // Call with current index configuration
            call_target_function(numberOfForLoops, indices);

            // Increment current loop. If it overflows, propagate the carry
            indices[index] += 1;
            while (index < numberOfForLoops && indices[index] == limits[index]) {
                indices[index] = 0;
                index += 1;
            }

            // If the highest dimension overflown, you are done
            if (index == numberOfForLoops) {
                return ...;
            }

            // If some dimension successfully incremented, all dimensions below it were reset to 0
            index = 0;
        }
```